# (#100) An event cannot have an end time in the past

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication

I am creating a Facebook event through [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) with the code below, and I get the following error.

> Unable to create event: {"error":{"message":"(#100) An event cannot have an end time in the past.","type":"OAuthException"}}

Here is my code:

```
include_once("class.xhttp.php");
$access_token    = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$data['post'] = array(
    'access_token' =>$access_token,
    'name' => 'test' ,
    'description' => 'test',
    'location' => 'test' ,
    'street' => 'test' ,
    'city' => 'test' ,
    'privacy_type' => 'OPEN',
    'start_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()),
    'end_time' => '2011-02-10 20:00',
);

$response = xhttp::fetch("https://graph.facebook.com/{$profile_id}/events", $data);
if($response['successful']) {
    $var = json_decode($response['body'], true);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($var);
    echo "</pre>";
    $url = "https://www.facebook.com/event.php?eid={$var[id]}";
    echo $url;
 }
 else {
     $error = "Unable to create event: {$response[body]}";
     echo $error;
 }
```

What is the awry?

Comment: Why don't you change the end_time to be in the future?

Comment: okay 'privacy_type' => 'OPEN' i want the privacy to be a facebook list kust like family,accquaint ,close friend etc  how can i do this??

Comment: @Mat i have already got the list id and aslo ids in that list now i wana make it visible to that list how to do this??

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an event that goes from now to some day before now. Switch it around, make the end-date now and the start date whenever you want (before now). The end date has to be later than the start date. Did I understand your question?

Comment: i have arrival time and departure time in my app i want start time to be arrival time and end time to be departure time...

Comment: But you can't. Why would you want that?